# Bug when app runs with Qt Creator and ubuntu

Tags: qt, qt-creator

When app runs with Qt Creator and Ubuntu and terminal with corresponding program is open, I can not open/edit any file of current project with Qt Creator.

If change tick Run in internal terminal it works fine.
Having the issue after last reinstall to 6.4.3 version.
Tried to change settings above, reinstalled Qt and OS (Ubuntu 20) few times, still same issues.
Some times it just freezes and I could not do any edits in Qt Creator, sometimes program popups message "Qt Edtitor does not respond"

Build & Run/General
[image]

Build & Run
[image]

Terminal
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that your system just doesn't have enough resources to support the version of Creator you're using?

Comment: mzimmers, it's not possible, it worked for more then 1 year, after I reinstalled Qt and OS this month problem appears

Comment: also I've I tick settings "Open in Inner Terminal" problem disappers, but I need to use external terminal

Comment: it most often related to online installer qt6 bug or smth, if i do install the same with cmd, it works fine, but it installs qt5 - > how to install qt6 and qt6 creator and all dependencies, if not qt online installer. Kindly advise

Answer (score 2):

solved, latest Qt6 requires latest Ubuntu build.
The guide below is correct stable Qt6 configuration install
https://web.stanford.edu/dept/cs_edu/resources/qt/install-linux

Comment: Checking the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/supported-platforms.html) might help more :)